# How to alter $scope variables via service

Tags: angularjs

I have a small app which creates and edits fees with three states (using ui-router): index, new, edit.  New and Edit same pretty much the same functionality so instead of having the code twice I would like to outsource it into a service.  The problem is when I try to alter variables tied to the $scope in either the newCtrl or editCtrl.  For example, both have this function:

```
$scope.removeFeeRule = function(){
  $scope.feeParameter = null;
  $scope.feeRule.multiplier = null;       
  $scope.feeRule.addend = null;
  $scope.feeRule.fee_suite_id = null;
  $scope.feeRule.fee_parameter_id = null;
}
```

How do I avoid this code duplication and move this into a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple service to manage fees. I prefer delete over setting to nulls.   I also prefer not to expose my objects in services so I generally add a `get`er to access the data.  If you really wanted to you could expose `FeeService.myFee` vs `FeeService.getFee()`

```
angular.module('yourmodule')
    .service('FeeService', FeeService)
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

function FeeService(){
   this.reset  = reset;
   this.getFee = getFee;

   var _currentFee = {};
   function getFee(){
      return _currentFee;
   }

   function reset(){
       delete _currentFee.feeParameter = null;
       delete _currentFee.multiplier = null;
       delete _currentFee.addend = null;
       delete _currentFee.fee_suite_id = null;
       delete _currentFee.fee_parameter_id = null;
       return _currentFee;
   }
}

function MyController($scope, FeeService){


   $scope.removeFeeRule = removeFeeRule;


   init();

   function init(){
      $scope.myFee = FeeService.getFee();

   }

   function removeFeeRule(){
      FeeService.reset();

   }

}
```

Comment: But $scope.feeRule.multiplier is set to ng-model on the form.  Would I have to set it every time it changes on the form?

Comment: No.  Once it's initialized it will be bound to the object `feeRule`  Can you show me the form code you are talking about ?